# Are videogames like Street Fighter workplace appropriate?

Tags: work-environment, harassment

I really want to organize quick video matches during the workday for fun, just 5 minutes vs an opponent and you go back to your seat.

But I'm hesitant because of the slight violence and certain scantily-dressed females like Cammy (sort of a joined swimsuit).

If I get permission and then someone walks by and sees stuff they don't like, I could still get into trouble, and probably cause all video games being banned or something.

Comment: Welcome to the site -- this really depends on your workplace, so it's best to get permission from your manager.

Comment: I will be more worried about all the people watching the games instead of working than Cammy outfit

Comment: Are you asking about *this particular video game*, or are you asking about whether or not to even organize this sort of event?

Answer (score 10):

### Not workplace appropriate

As someone who has worked in IT for 18+ years, I can say that businesses do not like games on their computers. And for good reason. *The business* owns the PC and is responsible for it. And for the network that game communicates over.

Therefore, IT divisions are, as a rule, fairly paranoid about these things. Most large companies will have very strict policies and procedures to get software approved through. IT must review the software, determine any risk it presents to the business (both from an IT security risk and a legal risk), and then determine how to license it for those PCs.

Some small companies don't seem to mind. But larger companies will consider this grounds to shut down your network access and can possibly even result in you being fired.

Some businesses might let you use their facility / internet service if the game is on your device (console or your home PC) but again, most won't like that either. Especially the home PC, since, again, the IT department cannot be sure your PC meets their rules for IT security. Bringing in a home PC elevates the risk to them, since it could bring a virus into their network.

If the game's rating is anything worse than T (Teen), then it could also involve someone filing a complaint with HR. Then again, if you get exciting while playing computer games (because gamers sometimes like to yell or cuss while gaming), this too could lead to complaints.

Check to see if your company has an acceptable use policy for IT equipment. Most larger businesses do. That will tell you how they view such things.

If there is no such policy, ask IT. But do so casually, in an non-official manner. "Hey, what's our rule on installing games on our PCs and playing them after hours?" If they don't say no, then you can make an official request.

But most businesses do not approve of such things.

Comment: +1 It's not so much about the content as it is about playing games on company equipment during company time. If you wanted to propose bringing in a console for some lunch hour sessions, that would be a different story.

Comment: This sounds more like it should be an after-hours thing than something in the workplace.

Comment: @Pete an after-hours *not at workplace* thing. Yeah, totally.

Comment: Steve Jobs was well known for his personal dislike of video games.  It took a long time before games of any sort made it on the Apple Store.  This is not a safe, neutral entertainment option.  Some people really hate it.